# Maximal Ideals of $F[x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}]$, $F$ not necessarily algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Suppose that $F$ is a field (not necessarily algebraically closed) and $R = F[x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}]$ is the ring of polynomials in $n$-variables. How can I classify the maximal ideals of $R$?

If $F = \overline{F}$, then the weak nullstellensatz, states that the maximal ideals of $R$ are the sets $I = (x_{1} - a_{1} , \dots , x_{n} - a_{n}) : a_{i} \in F , \forall i \in [n]$.

> Is it the case that the maximal ideals of $R$ when $F$ is not algebraically closed are $I = \{ f \in R : f(a_{1} , \dots , a_{n}) = 0 \} \text{ for some } a_{i} \in \overline{F}$? If so how does one prove it?

Could I argue that $I \subset \overline{I}$, where $\overline{I} \unlhd \overline{F}[x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}]$ is a maximal ideal of the ring of polynomials in $n$ -variables over the algebraic closure of $F$? However, I believe this argument does not consider the fact that $I$ is maximal.

Answer (score 6):

The characterization is correct. Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Then $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/M=F'$ is a field, and it's finitely generated as an algebra over $F$. Therefore $F'$ is a field extension of finite degree, and thus algebraic. Through embedding $F'\hookrightarrow \overline{F}$, extending the natural embedding $F\hookrightarrow \overline{F}$ to an embedding $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\hookrightarrow \overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, and defining a map $\overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to\overline{F}$ which takes $x_i\in \overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ to the image of $x_i$ under the composite map $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to F'\to \overline{F}$, we can consider the following commutative diagram of rings:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F[x_1,\cdots,x_n] @>{}>> F'\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n] @>{}>> \overline{F}
\end{CD}$$

Clearly the bottom map corresponds to a maximal ideal of $\overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, which must be of the form $(x_1-a_1,\cdots)$ for $a_i\in \overline{F}$ by the Nullstellensatz - equivalently, it is all polynomials in $\overline{F}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ which vanish on $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in\overline{F}^n$. The preimage of this maximal ideal inside $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is also maximal, and may be described exactly as the polynomials in $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ vanishing on $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in\overline{F}^n$. So we have shown the requested characterization.

Comment: How do we know that the diagram commutes? That is, there is some $\vec{a} \in \overline{F}^{n} : ev_{\vec{a}} \circ i_{1} = i_{2} \circ \pi$, where $i_{1} : F[x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}] \rightarrow \overline{F}[x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}]$, and $ev_{\vec{a}}$ denotes the evaluation map?

Comment: I've updated the post a little - the diagram commutes by definition.

Comment: Very nice answer, though I think it can be explained a bit more simply after you appeal to Zariski's lemma. To give an $F$-algebra morphism $\varphi \colon F[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}] \to S$ is to specify $n$ elements $s_{1}, \ldots, s_{n} \in S$ as the images of $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$, and the kernel of $\varphi$ is precisely the set of all polynomials $f \in F[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}]$ such that $f(s_{1}, \ldots, s_{n}) = 0$. In your notation, if $\pi \colon F[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}] \to F'$ denotes the canonical quotient map, then the composition of $\pi$ with some fixed embedding...

Comment: ...$F' \hookrightarrow \overline{F}$ has kernel exactly $M$. But as observed, if $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in \overline{F}$ denote the images of $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$, the kernel must be those elements of $F[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}]$ which vanish on $(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})$. (In particular, there is no need to appeal to the Nullstellensatz ''twice'' - the first use of Zariski's lemma is enough.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim you're right, that's also a nice way to finish - thanks for your contribution.