# Let $I ⊆ K[x_1 ,...,x_n ]$ be an ideal in a polynomial ring. Show that $\mathcal{I}_{K[x_1,...,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I))=\sqrt{I} $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

(A generalization of Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz) Let $K$ be a field
and $\overline K$ its algebraic closure. Let $I ⊆ K[x_1 ,...,x_n ]$ be an ideal in a polynomial
ring. Show that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}_{K[x_1,...,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I))=\sqrt{I}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I)=\{(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\in \overline {K^n}| f(\xi_1,...\xi_2)=0,\ for\ all\ f\in I\}
\\
\mathcal{I}_{K[x_1,...,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I))=\{f\in K[x_1,...x_n]|f(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)=0\ for\ all\ (\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\in \mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I)\}
\end{equation}

The $\supset$ is easy. For the converse, need to show that $f^k\in I$ for some $k$. And always have
$\sqrt{I}=\bigcap_{I\subset P}P$, $P$ is prime ideal in $K[x_1,...,x_n]$.

If $f\notin \sqrt{I}.$ Then there are some $P\supset I$ such that $f\notin P.$ $K[x_1,...,x_n]/P$ is a domain for this prime ideal. Then $K[x_1,...,x_n]/P$ is a finitely generated ring over K. Is there exists a maximal ideal $m$ such that $(K[x_1,...,x_n]/P)/m$ is $\overline K$. And let $x_i$ be $\xi_i.$ Then its a contradiction.

How can I get this. Or this ideal is right? What's the right way.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where exactly your efforts break down? Right now it is difficult to tell where exactly you need help.

Comment: How do you define $\mathcal V_{{\bar K}^n} (I)$?

Comment: I think $\mathcal{V}_{\overline {K^n}}(I)=\{(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\in \overline {K^n}| f(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)=0, for\ all f\in I\}$

Comment: I was going to imitate the algerbaic closed case. But the prime ideal in $K[x_1,...x_n]$ is unknow.. May be it's not a right way.

Comment: This problem is copied verbatim from Kemper's "A Course in Commutative Algebra" (it's exercise 1.9), just like your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633040/show-that-sqrtij-bigcap-p-in-mp) which is a (nearly) verbatim copy of 1.8 from the same book. Please add your attempts on this (homework?) problem so we can give you better help and hints without just giving away the exercise. If you're stuck, try some of the steps mentioned in [how to ask good questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: It's not homework. I'm studtying the book by my-self. At first I wanted to imitate the algebraic closed case. But I found that this would not work. For the general case, I don't know "structure" of prime ideal which would be effective. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, there are a number of things you could try to demonstrate some effort - one thing to do is trying a small example. For instance, what happens if you take something like $(x)\subset \Bbb Q[x,y]$? I have written and would be happy to provide a full solution to this if you demonstrate more of your efforts (via [edit]ing them in to your post), but until you do that in the question I don't think it would be wise on my part to give you an answer. (Final tip: I don't get notifications unless you @ me on these posts. Good luck!)

Comment: That's my attempt @KReiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, the inclusion $\supset$ is straightforwards. To prove the other inclusion, we need to show that if $f$ is an element of the LHS, then some power $f^k$ is in $I$.

To do this, let $J$ be the ideal of $\overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ generated by $I$ and let $f\in \mathcal{I}_{K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(I))$. We notice that $f\in \mathcal{I}_{\overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(J))$. By the usual Nullstellensatz, this means that $f\in\sqrt{J}$, so there's some positive integer $k$ so that $f^k\in J$. Since $f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\subset \overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then any power of $f$ is also in $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, so we get $f^k\in J\cap K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Since $\overline{K}$ is a $K$-vector space, we can find a splitting of the canonical injection $K\to \overline{K}$, also known as a $K$-linear projection $\overline{K}\to K$. Now we can extend this to a projection $\overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ by applying it to each coefficient of a polynomial. Call the resulting map $\varphi$: it is a $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$-linear map of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$-modules.

Now we use the definition of $J$ as $\overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$-linear combinations of elements from $I$ to write $f^k=\sum_i^n \alpha_i h_i$ where $\alpha_i\in \overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and $h_i\in I$. Apply $\varphi$ to both sides. Since $f^k\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, the LHS is unchanged, and similarly as $h_i\in I\subset K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, the $h_i$ are preserved as well. So our relation becomes $f^k = \sum_i^n \varphi(\alpha_i)h_i$, which demonstrates that $f^k\in I$ since the $\varphi(\alpha_i)$ are elements of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

This proof is how I would solve this if I were only working out of this text and hadn't developed much in the way of other tools.

---

I think there's a more intuitive way, but we'll need to gather some extra ingredients first and it might require a slightly longer explanation. It's somewhat similar to your recent attempt.

First, we identify the maximal ideals of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$: ever maximal ideal of this ring is of the form $\{f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\mid f(\alpha)=0\}$ for some $\alpha\in \overline{K}^n$. (See [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598030/maximal-ideals-of-fx-1-dots-x-n-f-not-necessarily-algebraically/3598096#3598096) of mine for a full proof.)

Next, we need some additional ring-theoretic technology. A (commutative) **Jacobson ring** is a ring in which every prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals. This means, in particular, that if we want to calculate the radical of an ideal in a Jacobson ring, it suffices to take the intersection of all maximal ideals containing this ideal. (Note this is very badly not true for non-Jacobson rings like $K[x,y]_{(x,y)}$.) It turns out that all finitely generated algebras over a field are Jacobson, so we can use this idea to give an explanation.

We start by writing $\mathcal{I}_{K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(I))=K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\bigcap\mathcal{I}_{\overline{K}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(J))$ where again $J$ is the ideal generated by $I$. Now, the right hand side on the right of the intersection is the radical of $J$ by the Nullstellensatz, so we're considering $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\bigcap\sqrt{J}$ now. On the other hand, by the fact about Jacobson rings above, we can rewrite $\sqrt{J}$ as the intersection of all maximal ideals containing $J$, so now we're considering $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\cap \left(\bigcap_{J\subset m} m\right)$.

Now we just swap the order of taking the intersections: $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\cap \left(\bigcap_{J\subset m} m\right) = \bigcap_{J\subset m} \left(K[x_1,\cdots,x_m]\cap m\right)$. Now we note three things: first, that $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\cap m$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$; second, that it contains $J\cap K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]=I$; and third, that every maximal ideal of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ containing $I$ can be obtained this way. This means this latter intersection is all the maximal ideals of $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ which contain $I$, so it is exactly $\sqrt{I}$ by our earlier work. Thus the claim is proven.

Comment: very thank you!